# How I can see my webView under Navigation Bar by transparency?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a question for you about navigation bar transparency.

Here a screenshot of my view:

[image]

It's just a UIWebView embedding an HTML page.

I want to make visible the web page under the navigation bar by transparency, but I don't know how to make that.

I've already add `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;` to the viewDidLoad method, but when I scroll the web page, nothing is visible by transparency.

How I can place the UIWebView frame under the navigation bar, but not the web page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find how to make that. Just add this in the viewDidLoad method :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.8f;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.navigationController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But I have now a little problem, the navigation bar is now black.
I tried to change the color of setBarTintColor (with an alpha value < 1.0) but when I do that, the navigation bar is not transparent.
Do you have an idea from where the black color come ?

Comment: make sure all the color setup on the interface builder is set to clearColor not default(sometimes default is not a clearColor)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use your own custom made navigation controller or interface builder? Sometimes I have the same problem with settings in interface builder.